# Having ssh tunneling itself for remote access from a third machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am struggling with understanding if and how the following is possible.

Say that I have a machine `T` (target) which I want to access from remote (ideally via `ssh`).

`T` is behind a router/firewall `R` and I cannot forward port (e.g.) `22` of `R` to port `22`  of `T`. 
In a word, no direct `ssh` access to `T` is possible.

Now say that

- I have a machine `A` on which I have full control.
- I can ssh from `T` to `A`, i.e.

  ```
    T:  ssh user@A
  ```

  succeeds.

**Q1:** can I use this to access shell of `T` from `A`? I.e., can I use the connection created from `T` to `A`, to use `T` from `A`?

```
   T ---> ssh ----> A          # this is possible               

   T <--- ? shell ? <---- A    # is this possible?
```

**Q2:** If *Q1* is possible:

Let's say that I have a third machine `L` (e.g. my laptop), and I aim at having access to the shell of `T` from `L`. Can I ssh-tunnel `A` access to `L`?

```
   T ----> ssh ----> A <---- ssh < ---- L

   T <-------  ?? %&£€ ?? <------- L       # is this possible?
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Is A publicly reachable?

Comment: @EeroAaltonen, Yes it is publicly reachable

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93351/22886 and links in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93349/ssh-connection-into-lan-without-port-forwarding#comment141216_93349. Or, if you can forward any port (not necessarily 22) from the router to your target, you can save yourself the hassle with reverse tunnelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course possible.

**Q1**: reverse tunneling over ssh is possible ?

*Yes*.
Here are some answers about reserve tunneling:

- (UL) [How does reverse SSH tunneling work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work)
- (UL) [SFTP over reverse SSH tunnel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82582/sftp-over-reverse-ssh-tunnel)

**Q2**: tunneling a reserved tunnel is possible ?

*Yes*, this is basically an ssh tunnel over a tunnel. Here are a few answers regarding tunnel into a tunnel:

- (UL) [Tunnel traffic through another machine over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/tunnel-traffic-through-another-machine-over-ssh)
- (UL) [log into a machine through another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118314/log-into-a-machine-through-another-with-decompression-at-the-ends-only/118318#118318)
- (UL) [How to put a tunnel in a tunnel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28270/how-to-put-a-tunnel-in-a-tunnel/28313#28313)

Comment: If you are stucked somewhere in the middle, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, in the other direction.  Firstly establish an reverse SSH tunnel from T to localhost on A, then tunnel from L to the A side of the AT tunnel, then use ssh to connect to the local part of the L-A tunnel, and you'll connect remotely through L-A-T.

In my example  A is listening for ssh connections on port 22123.
Locally I use the username user, remotely it's user.name.
I have keys locally called ~/.ssh/A_id_rsa and ~/.ssh/T_id_rsa to connect to the 2 machines A and T respectively as user.name.

Here is a script to connect the T-A tunnel, which should be run on T.

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_KEY="-i /home/user.name/.ssh/A_id_rsa"
REMOTE_USER="user.name"
GATEWAY_MACHINE="A.domain.com"
GATEWAY_SSH_PORT="22123"

ssh -N -R2201:127.0.0.1:22 -p ${GATEWAY_SSH_PORT} ${SSH_KEY} ${REMOTE_USER}@${GATEWAY_MACHINE}
```

Here is a script to connect the L-A tunnel, which should be run on L.

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_KEY="-i /home/user/.ssh/A_id_rsa"
REMOTE_USER="user.name"
GATEWAY_MACHINE="A.domain.com"
GATEWAY_SSH_PORT="22123"

ssh -N -L2201:127.0.0.1:2201 -p ${GATEWAY_SSH_PORT} ${SSH_KEY} ${REMOTE_USER}@${GATEWAY_MACHINE}
```

Then I add the following to my localhost's /etc/hosts file, so I can refer to the local side of the tunnel as T:-

```
127.0.0.1          T
```

Then I have this script, in our example called /usr/local/bin/T to connect to it

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_KEY="-i /home/user/.ssh/T_id_rsa"
REMOTE_USER="user.name"

ssh -p 2201 ${SSH_KEY} ${REMOTE_USER}@T
```

The T-A tunnel is reverse, so -R, the L-A tunnelr is local, so -L.  The -N in the scripts, prevents them from starting a shell to A, so I normally run that, either with a & to run it in the background or press ctrl+Z and run bg to do it, after having entered the password to unlock A_id_rsa if I haven't got it loaded into my keychain already.

Comment: If you don't have access to T to start the script all the time, then I suggest you run it as a service, so there is always a tunnel back to T from A on :2201